# Como customizar um listView (rolagem)?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

Dado uma Activity que possui um adapter para preencher uma lista de contatos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se possível queria obter o seguinte resultado como na imagem abaixo:

[image]

> Ao rolar pra cima e pra baixo, mostrar a letra inicial do elemento
>   listado no adapter.
>   **Obs: meu adapter preenche um lisView em que os
>   dados nele contido já se encontram em ordem alfabética crescente.**

Comment: Você já tentou utilizar uma ScrollView para resolver esse problema?

Comment: @leonardo A `ListView` já se comporta como uma `ScrollView`, isto é, faz _scroll_ sem necessidade de acrescentar uma `ScrollView`.

Comment: Nunca cheguei a implementar algo desse tipo, logo não consigo ajudar muito, mas esse artigo: http://androidopentutorials.com/android-listview-fastscroll/ detalha todos os pontos pra tentar chegar nesse resultado.

Comment: vou dar uma olha aki vlw pelo link @Wakim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solução com a ajuda do @Wakim^^:**

Aqui nesse link abaixo encontra-se as imagens para customização da barra de rolagem(**hospedas por mim no mega**) e devem ser colocadas no caminho **res/drawable**:

[Drawable - imagens customizadas](https://mega.co.nz/#F!7RYw2QDT!ZQ8ICZ0DcHOeri1TjyEirQ)

Passo a passo:

1. Criação da cor customizada no caminho **res/values/colors.xml**:

   ```
   <color name="apptheme_color">#DA4A38</color>
   ```
2. Você pode adiciona ao caminho **res/values/strings.xml**, os itens a serão mostrados posteriormente na interface, como por exemplo:

   ```
   <string-array name="fruits_array">
       <item>Apples</item>
       <item>Apricots</item>
       <item>Avocado</item>
       <item>Annona</item>
       <item>Banana</item>  
       <item>Bilberry</item>
       <item>Blackberry</item>
   </string-array>
   ```
3. Layout da activity **activity_main.xml** no caminho **res/layout**:

   ```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:padding="5dp"
       tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <ListView
       android:id="@android:id/list"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
4. Layout dos itens **list_item.xml** no caminho **res/layout**:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/txt_title"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:paddingBottom="10dp"
       android:paddingLeft="15dp"
       android:paddingTop="10dp" />
   ```
5. Estilo da barra de rolagem deve ser adicionada no caminho **res/values/styles.xml**:

   ```
   <resources>

       <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
       </style>

       <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
           <item name="android:fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/fastscroll_thumb_holo</item>
           <item name="android:fastScrollOverlayPosition">atThumb</item>
           <item name="android:fastScrollTextColor">@color/apptheme_color</item>
           <item name="android:fastScrollTrackDrawable">@drawable/fastscroll_thumb_pressed_holo</item>
           <item name="android:fastScrollPreviewBackgroundRight">@drawable/bg_default_focused_holo_light</item>
       </style>

   </resources>
   ```
6. Definição das caraterísticas da barra de rolagem quando pressionada **fastscroll_thumb_holo.xml** no caminho **res/drawable**:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

       <item android:drawable="@drawable/fastscroll_thumb_pressed_holo" android:state_pressed="true"/>
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/fastscroll_thumb_default_holo"/>

   </selector>
   ```
7. Criação de um **adapter**:

   ```
   public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements SectionIndexer {

       HashMap<String, Integer> mapIndex;
       String[] sections;
       List<String> fruits;

       public ListAdapter(Context context, List<String> fruitList) {
           super(context, R.layout.list_item, fruitList);
           this.fruits = fruitList;
           mapIndex = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
           for (int x = 0; x < fruits.size(); x++) {
               String fruit = fruits.get(x);
               String ch = fruit.substring(0, 1);
               ch = ch.toUpperCase(Locale.US);
               mapIndex.put(ch, x);
            }
           Set<String> sectionLetters = mapIndex.keySet();
           ArrayList<String> sectionList = new ArrayList<String>(sectionLetters);
           Collections.sort(sectionList);
           sections = new String[sectionList.size()];
           sectionList.toArray(sections);
       }

       public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
           return mapIndex.get(sections[section]);
       }

       public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
           return 0;
       }

       public Object[] getSections() {
           return sections;
       }
   }
   ```
8. Finalmente, a **MainActivity**:

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

       ListView fruitView;

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           fruitView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
           fruitView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
           String[] fruits = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fruits_array);
           List<String> fruitList = Arrays.asList(fruits);
           Collections.sort(fruitList);
           setListAdapter(new ListAdapter(this, fruitList));
        }
   }
   ```

> Consulta ao site ao exemplo: [Customização barra de rolagem](http://androidopentutorials.com/android-listview-fastscroll/)